# Как получить пароль с запроса mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь сделать проверку авторизации пользователя. Делаю проверка по нику, а потом нужно как то получить пароль и сравнить.

```html
$db = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database)
or die("Error " . mysqli_error($db));

$sql = "SELECT name, password FROM login WHERE name = '".addslashes($login_admin->nickname)."'";
        $res = $db->query($sql);
        $user = $db->fetch_assoc($res);
        if($login_admin->password == $user->password){
            echo "Ok";
        }else{
            echo "faslse";
        }
```

Получаю ошибку: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_assoc()

Comment: `$user = $res->fetch_assoc();` Документацию читайте http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php И `Извлекает результирующий ряд в виде ассоциативного массива`, а не объекта.

Comment: Если пишу $user = $res->fetch_assoc($res);  получаю Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_assoc() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in

Comment: Вы не видите, что у меня в комментарии написано?

Comment: Уже понял, не дочитал

Answer (score 2):

вместо 
`$db->fetch_assoc($res);`
нужно так 
`$res->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_assoc() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in

Comment: Неправильно скопировали мой совет, у меня не передаются параметры в fetch_assoc

Comment: Понял, спасибо)